# SAPUI5, How to: Create a Label/Text that is inline with a RadioButton Group (the Buttons also inline)

Tags: javascript, xml, frontend, sapui5, backend

I am working with SAPUI5, i just wondered how can i make the Text/Label be inline with a RadioButtonGroup,
with the Buttons that also inline.

Summarized: Text/Label inline with Buttons, that are also displayed inline.

What i tried:

```
<FlexBox alignItems="Start"
justifyContent="Center"> 

<Text text="An example of a group in warning state"/>
            <RadioButtonGroup valueState="Warning">
                <buttons>
                    <RadioButton id="RB4-1" text="Option 1"/>
                    <RadioButton id="RB4-2" text="Option 2"/>
                </buttons>
            </RadioButtonGroup>

</FlexBox>
```

What it does: It makes the Label/Text be inline with the RadioButtonGroup, however the Buttons are displayed as a block.

How do i achieve the formatting that i described?

[This how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlDE6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
<FlexBox alignItems="Center" 
    justifyContent="Center">

    <Text text="An example of a group in warning state" />
    <RadioButtonGroup columns="4" 
        valueState="Warning">
        <buttons>
            <RadioButton id="RB4-1" 
                text="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton id="RB4-2" 
                text="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton id="RB4-3" 
                text="Option 3" />
            <RadioButton id="RB4-4" 
                text="Option 4" />
        </buttons>
    </RadioButtonGroup>

</FlexBox>
```

RadioButtonGroup has the property `columns`. Multiple columns are displayed next to each other and not beneath.

If you set `alignItems` to `Center` the label and the radio buttons text are (more or less) vertically aligned.